# WIX: Unable to install app if i enable upgrade and uninstall a new build and try to install old one

Tags: wix, wix3.7, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am using WIX to create msi files. and i am using Major Upgrade. The upgrade works correctly but if uninstall new build, for example, Build 9 and install an old one (example 3), i got an error although nothing currently installed on my machine **This Version is older than installed one. Installation will exit.**
and this is my WIX Configuration.

```
<Product Id="*" Name="My App" Language="1033" Version="1.0.12"
           Manufacturer="MyApp" UpgradeCode="CDDBYUYB-7C1D-4B80-BA00-244ETERETE09A">
    <Package
      InstallerVersion="200" 
      Compressed="yes"
      InstallScope="perMachine"
      InstallPrivileges="elevated"/>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="MyApp.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/> 
    <MajorUpgrade
      AllowDowngrades="no" 
      DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" 
      AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no"
      IgnoreRemoveFailure="no"
      Schedule="afterInstallValidate" />
```

Comment: any help for this issue

Comment: There must be some leftovers from the package then. The `Version` is also different for the older build, right? In the code provided, the `Version="1.0.12"`. What is the `Version` of Build 9 and Build 3? Are there some components installed permanently?

Comment: Please, include relevant MSI logs created with /l*v switch. Otherwise it's just guessing why your installation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify that the upgrade works correctly. For example, if you did a per machine install, then a per user "upgrade" there would be no true upgrade because both products would still be installed. If you uninstalled the new per user setup it would leave the per machine one installed and then you couldn't downgrade it. There are similar scenarios with cross context "upgrades" in the vice versa situation. So these are guesses, not knowing the entire situation, and the info required would primarily be verbose logs of the initial install and the upgrade you say is working.

"Nothing on the machine" might be just use of ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1. Or if you've logged in under different credentials you won't see products installed under another account.  Because the same PackageCode can cause these types of issue it would be better if you had an auto-generated Id "*" in your Package element.

Take a verbose log of the upgrade and make sure it finds the old product.

It could be an MSI bug, but unlikely. The only time I've seen this issue is during a catastrophic machine crash that left partial UpgradeCode info on the system even though the product itself was not marked as installed. This is specific to the single machine, so you can verify if this is the issue by repeating the scenario on a clean machine (virtual machines are idea for this).

The easiest detour is to start again with a new UpgradeCode, making sure you always generate a new PackageCode on every build, changing ProductCode too, and on each major upgrade.

Comment: Hi philDw, how can i check if left partial upgradecode info is left on my machine and how to clean this issue.   Note, i have old build that works correctly but i cannot determine the cause of this issue. I watched my changes in TFS, but all related to custom actions i added

Comment: UpgradeCodes are obfuscated in HKLM\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrectVersion\Installer\UpgradeCodes where each node has a list of obfuscacted ProductCodes. Or use MsiEnumRelatedProducts(UpgradeCode..) to find them. Also perhaps in the equivalent in HKCU for per user installs.

Comment: Hi PhilDW, after watching the log file, i found this statement. it says that there is a downgrade detected but how to remove these entries and start with a clean state :  Property(C): WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED = {4D441EDE-DF5C-4D65-A5F1-DF7F75040C0D};{2FED60BE-34FA-4142-A84B-DBBAAF6A7F2B};{7794F5FD-6441-4317-89D0-294DFAA7B5DE};{7F2C40AF-99C9-46C6-B230-A92BCC64266C};{5569D2CC-30B3-42CD-8CB0-1CB5348F5468};{C6E65399-1F8C-43A1-A533-F370196EC246};{4C966063-18E2-40E9-987B-A3DADDA82ECD};{2C9DEDC0-1F23-4C30-BC47-27E5DFB7024C};{72A51A9A-A0A7-45C3-8026-A0237BD1CBC4};{64354ED7-6B98-44D9-B40C-5B5287A98647}

Comment: Hi PhilDW, i am waiting your response